# 404 page in magento for custom module

Tags: magento

I am new to magneto. I have created a custom module for webservice. I have done forgotpassword functionality but i am getting 404 page.

My folder structure for controller file:

```
 app/code/local/Blazedream/Oauth/controllers/Customer/AccountController
 class Blazedream_Oauth_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
   {
    public function forgotPasswordPostAction()
{

echo"hiiiii";exit;
  }
}
```

My config file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Blazedream_Oauth>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Blazedream_Oauth>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <oauth>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Blazedream_Oauth before="Mage_Oauth">Blazedream_Oauth</Blazedream_Oauth>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </oauth>
    </routers>
</frontend>
    </config>
```

My module is enabled.

My url to run the forgotPasswordPostAction

```
 http://xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/index.php/oauth/customer/account/forgotpasswordpost
```

I am getting 404 page, i dont know where i had done the mistake.

If i create a accountcontroller file without creating the customer folder inside controllers folder, Then it is executing and print "hiiiiiiiii"
but If i create folder, yhen it displays 404 page..

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking.  It sounds like your controller is working, but not when it's in the directory that you expected--is that correct?  Have you cleared (or disabled) the cache between config changes?

Comment: you are absolutely right. I have cleared cache, still i am getting 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
I used wrong url to run, the correct url is

http://xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/index.php/oauth/customer_account/forgotpasswordpost

Thanks for everyone replies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the "Customer" folder that please use below:

Blazedream_Oauth_Customer

```
<modules>
<Blazedream_Oauth before="Mage_Oauth">Blazedream_Oauth_Customer</Blazedream_Oauth>
</modules>

class Blazedream_Oauth_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
// your code
}
```